# Unable to send/receive data via HC-12/UART in Python

Tags: python, pyserial

I've written some code to communicate between two Raspberry Pi's, using identical HC-12 433Mhz transceivers. I was able to successfully echo between the two Pi's using a direct serial connection and `echo`/`cat`, however am unable to replicate this using HC-12s, which theoretically work by a similar principal. I'm using the port `ttyAMA0` on both for this example, but `ttyS0` is also available and have tried every combination of these ports.

The following code is common to both the sending and receiving, just writing once for sake of brevity:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = "/dev/ttyAMA0",
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
)
print("Serial status: " + str(ser.isOpen()))
```

This is the sending program:

```
while True:
    print("Sending...")
    ser.write("hello\n".encode())
    time.sleep(1)
```

And the receiving program:

```
while True:
    print("Receiving...")
    data = ser.readlines()
    print(data.decode())
```

The sending program simply loops as expected, but the receiver prints "Receiving...", and then nothing.

When I keyboard interrupt the receiving program at that point, it says it is currently up to `data = ser.readlines()`.

Any help would be much appreciated - I've spent the better part of the last week trawling and exhausting forums and READMEs to no avail, and this is literally my last option. Am close to insanity on this one!

Comment: `.readlines()`, with no timeout specified, is going to keep reading forever.  Try `.readline()` instead.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for the suggestion, but no luck - same result!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pyserial `readlines()` function relies on the timeout parameter to know when end-of-file is reached - this is warned about [in the doco](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline).  So with no timeout, the end never occurs, so it keeps buffering all lines read *forever*.

So you can just add a timeout to the serial port open, and your existing code will begin to work.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port     = "/dev/ttyAMA0",
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity   = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout  = 2                        # seconds     # <-- HERE
)
```

A better approach might be to use `readline()` (note singular, no 's'), for each line in turn:

```
print( "Receiving..." )
while True:
    try:
        data = ser.readline()
        print( data.decode() )
        # TODO - something with data
    except:
        print( "Error reading from port" )
        break
```

As that will allow the code to act on the input line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Serial.read_until`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/v3.4/serial/serialutil.py#L650) method. The default termination character is `\n`.

For example,

```py
data = ser.read_until()
print(data)
```